# maven-surefire-plugin Crashes after Upgrading to springboot-starter-parent:2.1.8.RELEASE

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to upgrade the dependencies for a Java application that my team maintains. The application is based on SpringBoot and used to declare `spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.6.RELEASE` as its parent.

After the upgrade, the application declares `spring-boot-starter-parent:2.1.8.RELEASE` as its parent. Here's the diff of my pom.xml file:

```
     <parent>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
-        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
+        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
         <relativePath/>
     </parent>
```

Now `mvn -X clean test` now fails with the following exception:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) on project scimapi: There are test failures.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\musikpolice\Documents\git\scimapi\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
[ERROR] The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\musikpolice\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4062831518056119279\surefirebooter1476719102492403846.jar C:\Users\musikpolice\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4062831518056119279 2019-10-01T11-33-46_847-jvmRun1 surefire6827784388561767102tmp surefire_04733578287828383905tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.mycompany.scim.controllers.SomeControllerTest
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
[ERROR] Command was cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\java" -jar C:\Users\musikpolice\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4062831518056119279\surefirebooter1476719102492403846.jar C:\Users\musikpolice\AppData\Local\Temp\surefire4062831518056119279 2019-10-01T11-33-46_847-jvmRun1 surefire6827784388561767102tmp surefire_04733578287828383905tmp"
[ERROR] Process Exit Code: 0
[ERROR] Crashed tests:
[ERROR] com.mycompany.scim.controllers.SomeControllerTest
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:669)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:282)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:245)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1183)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1011)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:857)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:954)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:192)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[ERROR]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[ERROR]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
[ERROR]         at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

The `C:\Users\musikpolice\Documents\git\scimapi\target\surefire-reports` directory mentioned in the test output does not exist. I cannot find the dump files referenced in the output either.

My Maven/Java versions are as follows:

```
Apache Maven 3.5.4 (1edded0938998edf8bf061f1ceb3cfdeccf443fe; 2018-06-17T14:33:14-04:00)
Maven home: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I am not explicitly declaring a version of the `maven-surefire-plugin` in the Builds > Plugins section of pom.xml, but adding an explicit reference to version 2.22.2 of that plugin did not resolve the problem.

It's worth noting that adding an `@Ignored` annotation to `com.mycompany.scim.controllers.SomeControllerTest` doesn't fix the problem - the next test in line just fails in the same way.

Interestingly, the code compiles and all tests pass in IntelliJ. I only run into this issue when running the build with Maven, which tells me that the problem is likely some mismatched versions of elements in my toolchain, but I don't really know what else to troubleshoot.

Comment: Take a deep look at your tests: `on project scimapi: There are test failures.
[ERROR]`...Are you using JUnit or JUnit Jupiter ? Or Test NG ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using JUnit v4.12. It is a transitive dependency of spring-boot-starter-test. More importantly though, the tests pass when run in IntelliJ, so this is definitely a Maven issue, not an issue with the test code.

Comment: Please share `maven-surefire-plugin` section of the POM file.

Comment: As noted in the OP, I did not explicitly include a `maven-surefire-plugin` in my `build` configuration. I have also attempted to explicitly include version `2.22.2` of that plugin, but it did not resolve the issue.